# VBA counter logic behind

Tags: excel, vba, counter

I wonder what is the logic behind a counter in VBA.

Let's say within a loop we have:

```
For x = 2 To lr
    If dbsheet.Cells(x, 4) = cat And dbsheet.Cells(x, 5) = lname Then
        counter = counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3)
    End If
```

counter = counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3) looks like 3 = 3 + 2 to me. I know what it does (in my case sums up numbers which match certain criteria), but I don't understand the logic behind.

Can someone explain this or at least provide me with some web links?

Thank you, Miha

Comment: What's your question? `counter` is a variable. First time it's called, has value of `0` (unless declared elsewhere to have some value). So, then you have `[variable] = [current value] + [cell value]`...Think of the code working from RIGHT to LEFT. It takes the cell's value, add's to `counter`'s value, then sets that value as the new `counter`.

Comment: If variable is on the left of equal sign it's it will assign to that variable and if it's on the right it will get the value of the variable. So the statement is more like `count = 3 + 2` or  `counter.set(3 + 2)`

Comment: There's no real logic here, just simple addition and assignment

Comment: It is not logic, but convention.  The conventions in programming languages do not always follow the same conventions that you would expect in algebra.  In this case the equals sign does not mean the left side equals the right side as it would in algebra.  Instead it means assign the value of the expression on the right side to the variable on the left.

Comment: This explains it better: https://www.learneroo.com/modules/11/nodes/102

Comment: Since I do not have enough "reputation" here I can not give you upvotes. Guys, thank you, this is gold for me as I have just started a few days ago. Have a nice one

Answer (score 0):

The `counter` is a variable. Variables are just something you have that represents something else.

When you want to assign a variable a value in VBA it always follows the same format, or syntax.
The variable to be changed will be present before the operator and the information that modifies the variable is after the operator.

With `x = 2` the variable to be changed is `x`, the operator is `=` and the target value for the variable is `2`. You also don't know what `x` is until you know what it will become.

The logic applies when you expand it.

`counter = counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3)` is no different.
Here we have `counter` before the operator `=` that is modified by `counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3)`.

So you need to know what `counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3)` is before you can evaluate the result of what `counter` will ultimately become.

Another way to write this to understand what is happening would be this:

```
For x = 2 To lr
If dbsheet.Cells(x, 4) = cat And dbsheet.Cells(x, 5) = lname Then
    counter2 = counter
    counter = counter2 + dbsheet.Cells(x, 3)
End If
```

Essentially it boils down to adding a number to itself.